# How find out gem install options?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install all my gems in ~/.gems. I wanted to install ferret as user but it doesn't work, because ferret need to install in /usr/bin. 
My question is, how to I find out which options (like install to different bin folder) exists, when I install gems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you're mentioning are used by extconf.rb when the installation is being configured. Following steps would compile drivers that need to know where the system or API libraries are.

See [Creating an Extension](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html#S5)  in the "Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide" book.

Comment: Something you might want to consider is to use RVM. It creates a sandbox for your Ruby, or Rubies, and the gems associated with it. Everything will live in your ~/.rvm directory by default, though you can configure system-wide installations if you want. Once RVM is in control gems get installed into ~/.rvm also. Occasionally you'll have to intervene, but the RVM site has good info about the options you'll need. Highly recommended: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Answer (score 0):

As shown below `gem -h` will show you all the options the gem command can process....

[image]

Comment: I mean different options like I used it by mysql

gem install mysql -- \
  --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib \
  --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include